# what is difference between ShowFooter and FooterRow.Visible

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

what is is the difference between `gvService.ShowFooter = false; and 
                gvService.FooterRow.Visible = false;`.

Could you please tell me which one to use?

Comment: Are you talking about datagrid or gridview control?

Answer (score 3):

FooterRow is represents the footer row in a GridView control.

ShowFooter property is Gets or sets a value indicating whether the footer row is displayed in a GridView control.

Use the FooterRow property to programmatically access the GridViewRow object that represents the footer row in a GridView control. Initially we can set FooterRow visible true or false when creating grid view. But FooterRow property is available only after the GridView control creates the footer row in the RowCreated event.